# What does it means if its written like function(){}.bind(this));

Tags: jquery

I have a function in code which is declared like this

```
$get(URL, function (status, result) {}.bind(this));
```

**What is role of bind in it ?**

Comment: It binds the context of the callback function to `this`. Read the [`Function.prototype.bind` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).